# Linux shell script program quitting after line 29?

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, sh, raspbian

i am writing a shell script to create a user and add them to a group. i have come across a hurdle on line 17 when i have accounted an error which can be seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Q6B.jpg
but half of the code seems to be perfect (in terms of adding the user) but can anyone help me with this thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
let repeat=1
let counter=0
while [ $repeat -eq 1 ];
        do
        echo "Please enter the username for the created user"
        read username
        sudo useradd -m $username
        echo ""
        sudo passwd $username
        let counter=$counter+1
        while [ $repeat -eq 1 ];
                do
                echo "please enter the name of the group to put the user into"
                read group
                if [ $(getent group $group) ]; then #line 17 
                        sudo usermod -G $group,sudo $username
                        let repeat=0
                else
                        echo "The group "$group$" does not exist on our system"
                        echo "Do you want to create it as a new group (y)"
                        read input
                        if [ $input == "y" ]; then
                                sudo groupadd $groups
                                sudo usermod -G $group,sudo $username
                                let repeat=0

                        fi

                fi

         done
         echo $username" has beem added to the group "$group
   done

   echo "You have now created "$counter" new user(s) and have added them to their new group(s)"
```

Comment: which one is line 17?

Comment: why do you have `''''` ? only `''` should be enough to identify empty string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of the group is invalid, `getent group $group` won't return any
output so line 17 will be equivalent to:

```
if [ != '' ]; then
```

The `!=` operator compares strings before and after the operator. If one of
the required strings is missing, the shell reports the error:

```
[: !=: unary operator expected
```

If you want to check for a valid group, you can simply check that some output
is returned:

```
if [ $(getent group $group) ]; then
```

Comment: As soon as it gets to ," do you want to create it as a new group" it closes the terminal for no reason ??

Comment: @blawrence You have too many arguments for the `[` command in line 22: `if [ [ $input == "y" ] ]`. You only need `if [ $input == y ]`.